# ArrayList<User> Friends. VkApi

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to display my VK friendlist.

```
private  ArrayList<User> Friends = new ArrayList<User>();
Friends = api.getFriends(account.user_id, "first_name, last_name",null, null, null);
```

I got friendlist in logs.

```
I/Kate.Api﹕ response= 
    {
        "response": {
            "count":33,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id":23260033,
                    "first_name":"",
                    "last_name":"",
                    "online":0
                },
                {
                    "id":129188949,
                    "first_name":"",
                    "last_name":"",
                    "online":0
                }, ...
            ]
        }
    }
```

After it i try to display myfriendlist with Adapter.

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayList<User>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Friends);
```

I understand that Android Studio show me that error is in Friends, because it has type- `ArrayList<User>`.
But I can't understand how convert my `ArrayList<User> Friends` to `String[]` to display my friendlist on the screen? Or if i think wrong, how  implement my friendlist correctly?

Comment: You can use a custom adapter.

Comment: I know it's discouraged to downvote questions from new comers but this one evidently shows a lack of research to me. Please read android guide on `Adapters` first ! Here for example : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my stupid question

Answer (score 1):

MAybe using [ASNE library](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) and [asne-vk](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Casne-vk) make your life easier?
Just add dependency to your project:

```
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-vk:0.2.0'
...
}
```

setup and request friends like

```
socialNetwork.requestGetFriends();
```

And you can easily add another social network